# javascript and http session

Tags: javascript

Can we set variables in HTTP Sessions using javascript?

A good approach which will have three basic methods-

add a key, remove a key and read a key.

This should not be a cookie but the actual http session.

Comment: What do you call a "http session" ?

Comment: yes. we can do this using AJAX .

Answer (score 3):

No, the HTTP session lives on the server-side and is only accessible there. On the client side you (at most) have access to session key (as cookie), which is not enough.

In order to modify the HTTP session you must send HTTP request to the server (either normal or AJAX) describing the nature of modification. The request will be handled by the server, performing required session mutation.

To read session key you must also call the server but this time ask the server to read from HTTP session. The response should contain the session key value.